# wget http://kforge.ros.org/rososx/homebrew/raw-file/tip/electric/rosdep.yaml Unauthorized

Tags: ros, kforge, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

A while ago I successfully installed ROS Electric on Mac OSX, now I am trying to re-do all the [steps](http://ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/OSX/Homebrew) on another Mac but there is an issue that wasn't there last time (that my fish memory can recall).

When trying to get the rosdep.yaml file from kforge.ros.org:

```
wget http://kforge.ros.org/rososx/homebrew/raw-file/tip/electric/rosdep.yaml -O ~/.ros/rosdep.yaml
--2013-02-15 16:28:13--  http://kforge.ros.org/rososx/homebrew/raw-file/tip/electric/rosdep.yaml
Resolving kforge.ros.org... 70.35.54.212
Connecting to kforge.ros.org|70.35.54.212|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Authorization failed.
```

Should I get the file from somewhere else? I have been "googleing" but don't seem to find it.

Thank you very much in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55265/wget-http://kforge.ros.org/rososx/homebrew/raw-file/tip/electric/rosdep.yaml-unauthorized/) by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5625 on 2013-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have the original rosdep.yaml on another machine?

If so I can put it back up in its original location.  I think I might have removed the repository thinking it was no longer used.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

UDPATE:

It has been restored:

http://kforge.ros.org/rososx/homebrew/raw-file/tip/electric/rosdep.yaml

---

Originally posted by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) with karma: 1626 on 2013-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2013-02-16**:
I was thinking the same, I have the rosdep.yaml file from the other computer, I will post it on Monday and let you know how the installation went. Thanks!

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2013-02-17**:
I've posted the file here: http://pastebin.com/BUjae2Ty